# Has a Russian Tu-95 ever had to make an emergency landing in Europe?

Tags: military, tupolev

Has a Tu-95 Bear bomber ever made an emergency landing in a European country while the flight was on a mission to test the country's defences?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Aviation.SE. Unfortunately your question will probably be closed as too broad if you don't narrow it down

Comment: @kepler22b Not sure how this could be any more specific?

Comment: @JayCarr he could ask with some details like --which countries of Europe?,Europe is big--  When? For example from 1960-1970-- etc. :)

Comment: @kepler22b I would agree if it were something that were likely a common occurance (like general aircraft accidents).  But a Tu-95 crashing anywhere in Europe at any time (let alone while testing radar defenses) would be a significant event.  So no further detail is really required.  It's like the U-2 spy plane incident, for example.  You don't really have to specify a place or time because shooting down the U-2 was such a singular event, no further details are required beyond "Has a U-2 ever been shot down."

Comment: @JayCarr k,  let's see what the answer says...

Comment: the reason I asked is that with the huge distance these aircraft fly(now even close to the usa) and the age of the aircraft,it seems pure luck that they have never had a tech problem where they would have to put down in nato countries if unable to return to Russia or the old soviet union.

Comment: You do realize that Russia is in Europe right ?

Comment: If we think about the Cold War, I wouldn't think they'd even be able to enter the airspace of, say, a NATO country.  If they weren't over those countries in the first place, why would they land in them?  You could imagine a situation where an emergency arises over international waters, but you might then expect their orders would be to ditch at sea rather than try to land in an unfriendly country.

Comment: @Antzi Really?  By which defintion?  I think the question is clear.

Comment: @Simon most of the population lives west of the Ural mountain range, which lies in what is usually assumed to be Europe. It's a but iffy with Europe and Asia being mostly the same continent though.

Comment: I think the clue is in my question! I do realise that they do not enter other countries airspace(if they did,and were shot down,then I would place a bet that the start of a conflict could be predicted)but my question was,while flying over international waters,and a tech emergency took place,has permission ever been given in a mayday situation been given to land in a nato country.and yes I do know Russia has part of it in Europe as I live in Europe,and know these things!

Comment: A possible hostile bomber trying to make a emergency landing in a airfield strategicaly near their border... seens legit on the other hand outcomes can range from it being shot down to a nuclear war

Answer (score 3):

Not that anyone knows of. A couple of Bears have crashed within Russia's borders.

They usually fly over international waters only, so if one did go down there would be a chance it would sink without a trace.

Comment: Sink. Or be sunk, just to be sure.